# knapsack not giving correct output when using large numbers

Tags: c++, knapsack-problem

Before starting the question let me introduce myself. I am a Mobile Developer currently working in Warsaw and spending my free time on interview preparations. I started to prepare for interviews two years ago. At that time I should say I could not solve the two-sum problem. Easy problems seemed to me like hard ones so most of the time I had to look at editorials and discuss sections. Currently, I have solved ~800 problems and time to time participate in contests. I usually solve 3 problems in a contest and sometimes 4 problems. Ok, let's come back to the topic.

Here is the top-down approach of dynamic programming, knapSackRec is implemented recursively. But it's not working on the given test case:

```
W=5,
n=5,
wt{1,1,1,1,1},
v{1000000000,1000000000,1000000000,1000000000,1000000000,}
```

It is returning `2000000000` as output. But the correct output should be `5000000000`.

My code is here:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int static dp[102][1000005];

// Returns the value of maximum profit
int knapSackRec(int W, int wt[], int val[], int i)
{
    // Base condition
    if (i < 0)
        return 0;

    if (dp[i][W] != -1)
        return dp[i][W];

    if (wt[i] > W) 
    {
        // Store the value of function call
        // stack in table before return

        return dp[i][W] = knapSackRec(W, wt, val, i - 1);
    }
    else 
    {
        // Store value in a table before return

        // Return value of table after storing
        return dp[i][W] = max(
                val[i] + knapSackRec(W - wt[i], wt, val, i - 1),
                knapSackRec(W, wt, val, i - 1)
        );
    }
}
    
int main()
{
    int val[] = { 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000 };
    int wt[]  = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    int W = 5;
    int n = sizeof(val) / sizeof(val[0]);
    memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));

    cout << knapSackRec(W, wt, val, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to invest some time into learning proper C++ rather than picking bad habits from unprofessional coding websites.

Comment: It is because of integer overflow. The value `1000000000` is out of the range of integer. Just use long long int instead of int and it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your toolchain and platform, but most likely your values overflowed as your expected output is above the `INT_MAX` (I will assume x86 platform). BTW these technical pieces of information (OS, platforms, versions of stuff) are much more valuable to us, than your life backstory.

See ranges of other types:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/cpp-integer-limits?view=msvc-160

`INT_MAX    Maximum value for a variable of type int.   2147483647`

Could you try to run this:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
long long static dp[102][1000005];

// Returns the value of maximum profit
long long knapSackRec(long long W, long long wt[], long long val[], long long i)
{
    // Base condition
    if (i < 0)
        return 0;

    if (dp[i][W] != -1)
        return dp[i][W];

    if (wt[i] > W) 
    {
        // Store the value of function call
        // stack in table before return

        return dp[i][W] = knapSackRec(W, wt, val, i - 1);
    }
    else 
    {
        // Store value in a table before return

        // Return value of table after storing
        return dp[i][W] = max(
                val[i] + knapSackRec(W - wt[i], wt, val, i - 1),
                knapSackRec(W, wt, val, i - 1)
        );
    }
}
    
int main()
{
    long long val[] = { 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000 };
    long long wt[]  = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    long long W = 5;
    long long n = sizeof(val) / sizeof(val[0]);
    memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));

    cout << knapSackRec(W, wt, val, n);
    return 0;
}
```

As for you interview preparation, be able to solve random and obscure mathematical and algorithmic problems is great, but it's not good to replace that with good code fundamentals and good coding style. It's actually shocking to claim to solve 800 problems and missing such thing as overflow, if I would have to guess, I would guess this could go against you on a interview.

Knowing at least roughly when the types might overflow, that these change on platforms. Or fail modes of float/double types and what to avoid. What is volatile etc... Knowing well basics of the language are more valuable than knowing how to solve some abstract math problem.

I edited your question and fixed these, but would recommend developing a coding style and stick with it. Do you want to use `{` on the same line or on the next line, I'm not going to argue for one or another, but choose one and stick with it, do not change it inside one function.

I removed the indentation from the multiline knapSackRec variables, I like to split logically the arguments to multiple lines as well, however then use it that way consistently. Getting into a habit of putting newlines in some places (and how many of them). Or maybe learning MISRA and be able to code with it, for example if you would solve a coding problem on an interview and state that it's MISRA C compliment then I would be really impressed. There is much more than just having code that works, but it's not understood why exactly, not understood when it will fail (like the overflows) and it's hard to read.

For example, MISRA C has rule for a single return statement:
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/07/26/in-defence-of-misra/

Knowing how to code the solution and make it work is great, but if you would offer on the interview that now you can clean it up and re-write it to be fully MISRA C (or another standard) compliment then I think any interviewer should give you bonus points for that.